# How to send email in richtext format to Outlook?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, richtext

It works great to send emails (to Outlook) in HTML format by assigning the text/html content type string like so:

```
using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
{
  message.From = new MailAddress("--@---.com");
  message.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("--@---.com");
  message.To.Add(new MailAddress("---@---.com"));
  message.Subject = "This subject";
  message.Body = "This content is in plain text";
  message.IsBodyHtml = false;

  string bodyHtml = "<p>This is the HTML <strong>content</strong>.</p>";

  using (AlternateView altView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(bodyHtml,
    new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)))
  {
    message.AlternateViews.Add(altView);
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress);
    smtp.Send(message);
  }
}
```

The email is correctly recognized as HTML in Outlook (2003).
But if I try rich text:

```
MediaTypeNames.RichText;
```

Outlook doesn't detect this, it falls back to plain text.
How do I send email in rich text format?

Comment: Please show the source of the mail, so that we can determine whether it is a problem in Outlook or in the .net framework: http://www.outlook-tips.net/howto/view_source.htm

Comment: @Heinzi, sorry this is within Exchange so the instructions you linked to doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any other way to view the email source?

Comment: Do you have some other, non-exchange mail address you can send your mail to? Most webmail providers offer some way to see the "source" of the mail. Alternatively, you can send it to me (my mail address is at the top of my homepage, which is linked on my SO profile), and I'll add the source to your question.

Comment: I dont think you can do this, as I think you will need to craete a winmail.dat some how ..

Comment: BTW, just to make sure: You *are* using rich text (`{\rtf1 This is the RTF {\b content}.}`) rather than HTML (`This is the RTF <b>content</b>`) as the first parameter to `AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString`, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bottom line is, you can't do this easily using System.Net.Mail.

The rich text in Outlook is sent as a winmail.dat file in the SMTP world (outside of Exchange).

The winmail.dat file is a TNEF message. So, you would need to create your richtext inside of the winmail.dat file (formatted to TNEF rules).

However, that's not all. Outlook uses a special version of compressed RTF, so, you would also need to compress your RTF down, before it's added to the winmail.dat file.

The bottom line, is this is difficult to do, and unless the client really, really needs this functionality, I would rethink it.

This isn't something you can do with a few lines of code in .NET.

Comment: Yes, I have investigated this further and I have come to the same conclusion. There are some helper methods in the Exchange SDK, but these are dependent on the managed Exchange assemblies, which are not freely distributable.

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this by adding another alternate view before your calendar view as below:

```
var body = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(bodyHtml, new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html"));
mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(body);
```

Comment: Thanks, Now I can send rich text mail using this method.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me..

```
public void sendUsersMail(string recipientMailId, string ccMailList, string body, string subject)
    {
        try
        {  
            MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
            Msg.From = new MailAddress("norepl@xyz.com", "Tracker Tool");
            Msg.To.Add(recipientMailId);
            if (ccMailList != "")
                Msg.CC.Add(ccMailList);
            Msg.Subject = subject;
            var AltBody = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html"));
            Msg.AlternateViews.Add(AltBody);
            Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.xyz.com");
            smtp.Send(Msg);
            smtp.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
        }
    }
```