# Formatting Text in Resource file

Tags: asp.net, email, c#-4.0

I have a site that sends a variety of different emails. these are stored in a resx file. (The emails are sent as text not html, or else I suspect that what I am asking would be a lot easier)

I have now been asked to make some of the text in one of the emails bold. so that, for example I can have

**We can accept your decision now...** instead of We can accept your decision now...

I have tried creating my formatted text in word, and then cutting / pasting it into the resource file, but that strips out all the encoding.
Is there any way of storing formatting within the file, or do I need to rethink my approach? (In which case, I guess I either split the email into fragments, and when I am assembling the final string, I apply a font style to the relevent fragments, or I store my formatted emails in files and folders, and load them as required.)

Answer (score 0):

You should insert HTML in your text , `"<b> We can ac...</b>"`  will result in bold text in the receivers end.

Comment: The problem is the text is being sent via plain text, so if I do that I end up with the html code being printed out.

Comment: if you send it in plain text there is no way to format the mail body

Comment: The business will have to stick to plain text then, or accept html mail then, as I have been unable to get it to send anything in rich text. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a HTML format, you should create your email in a **RTF** format. It is not possible to bold your text if you are sending just a plain email. How to send it depends on the library you use for sending emails.

I've sent a **RTF formatted email** (with normal and bold text) from **MS Outlook 2013**, and the source code looks like that (similar like in HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2">
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server version rmj.rmm.rup.rpr">
<TITLE>Test</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<!-- Converted from text/rtf format -->

<P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="pl"></SPAN><SPAN LANG="en-us"><FONT FACE="Calibri">We can accept your decision now...</FONT></SPAN><SPAN LANG="pl"></SPAN><SPAN LANG="en-us"></SPAN></P>

<P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="pl"><B></B></SPAN><B><SPAN LANG="en-us"><FONT FACE="Calibri">We can accept your decision now...</FONT></SPAN></B><SPAN LANG="pl"><B></B></SPAN><B><SPAN LANG="en-us"></SPAN></B></P>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I am using the built in .net SMTP and MailMessage classes, which then hand off the messages to hMail server.

Comment: Using standard .NET library it is probably not possible. Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109563/how-to-send-email-in-richtext-format-to-outlook So typically, you should use plain text or HTML.