# Unable to send richtext content type mail to outlook using java mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am sending mail to outlook using java mail api. I am able to send plain text and html content mail but when I set content type to text/richtext but I receive mail in plain text only.

Can any body suggest how to send richtext mail? Here is what I tried:

```
// the parent or main part if you will
Multipart mainMultipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

// this will hold text and html and tells the client there are 2 versions of the message (html and text). presumably text
// being the alternative to html
Multipart htmlAndTextMultipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

// set html
MimeBodyPart htmlBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
htmlBodyPart.setContent("Hi", "text/richtext");
htmlAndTextMultipart.addBodyPart(htmlBodyPart);

MimeBodyPart htmlAndTextBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
htmlAndTextBodyPart.setContent(htmlAndTextMultipart);
mainMultipart.addBodyPart(htmlAndTextBodyPart);

message.setContent(mainMultipart);
```

Comment: It would help if you added some richtext formatting - otherwise the difference is not there.

Comment: Yes but outlook shows content type on the top of mail. So we can easily identify content type .

Comment: Your text **is** plain text. Have you looked at the headers in outlook?

Comment: I mean if I am sending content type as richtext, whatever I send outlook should show content type richtext on the top of mail in bracket like Message-(Rich text)

Comment: Check the headers. How it's **displayed** by your client is a whole different story

Comment: Exchange will sometimes "canonicalize" the message and convert it to something that it thinks will be better for the client.  Maybe it's converting your rich text into plain text?

Comment: yes @Bill this may be happening,but is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: I'm not an Exchange expert.  I think there are some settings in Exchange that provide some amount of control over this, but I don't know the details.  If you own the Exchange server, you might want to explore its settings.  If you determine that Exchange is in fact doing this, you might want to ask an Exchange-specific question about how to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

First - try adding richtext as content, not plaintext:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0 {\fonttbl {\f0 Courier;}}
{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;}
This line is the default color\line
\cf2
\tab This line is red and has a tab before it\line
\cf1
\page This line is the default color and the first line on page 2
}
```

In code it might look like

```
htmlBodyPart.setContent("{\\rtf1\\ansi\\deff0 {\\fonttbl {\\f0 Courier;}}\r\n" +
"{\\colortbl;\\red0\\green0\\blue0;\\red255\\green0\\blue0;}\r\n" +
"This line is the default color\\line\r\n" +
"\\cf2\r\n" +
"\\tab This line is red and has a tab before it\\line\r\n" +
"\\cf1\r\n" +
"\\page This line is the default color and the first line on page 2\r\n" +
"}", "text/richtext");
```

Then you might want to think about actually *providing* an alternative text - so you could have two different versions.

Last it helps a lot to use an email client that allows you to look at the MIME source of the received message - like Mozilla Thunderbird does.

Comment: do I need to copy and paste this in content?

Comment: I have tried above and also took example richtext but it sends it as it is, in header it shows multipart/related and on the top of mail it shows plain text

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109563/how-to-send-email-in-richtext-format-to-outlook  but how to create winmail.dat or tnef Can you please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly are you getting confused between [text/richtext](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1341) and [text/rtf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)

These are 2 different formats and is not related to HTML.

Comment: I have tried both but outlook doesn't show richtext